# Three.js camera position shows three coordinates for 360 video

Tags: three.js

I have used a 360 video player, when I change the camera position and prints the value it shows all the three coordinates. Shouldn't it show only 2 coordinates while the third should remain constant.I am printing the Camera.position coordinates in render() function.

```
<html>

<body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r73/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/211120/orbitControls.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="testButton">TEST</a>
<a href="#" id="testButton2">TEST2</a>
<script>
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(width, height);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var video      = document.createElement('video');
video.autoplay = true;
video.src    = 'https://streams.kolor.com/streams/833ec36d-b115-43a2-bbf1-aaca49046bab/source.02-720p_HD.mp4';

video.crossOrigin = '';
videoTexture = new THREE.Texture(video);
videoTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
videoTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
videoTexture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;


  var scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var cubeGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(500, 60, 40);
  var sphereMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: videoTexture});
  sphereMat.side = THREE.BackSide;
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, sphereMat);
  scene.add(cube);



  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 0.1, 10000);
  camera.position.y = 50;
  camera.position.z = 100;
  //camera.position.set(0,50,100);

  scene.add(camera);

  var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera);

  controls.enableDamping = true;
  controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
  controls.enableZoom = false; 
  controls.maxDistance = 50;
  controls.minDistance = 50;

  function render() {
          if( video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA ){
            videoTexture.needsUpdate = true;
          }
          controls.update(); 
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
          requestAnimationFrame(render);
          console.log("X:"+camera.position.x +"Y:"+camera.position.y+"Z:"+camera.position.z);
  }

  render();

  // test button function
// this does not work
var testButton = document.getElementById('testButton');
testButton.onclick = function ()
{
     //camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(50,60,70));
     camera.position.y = 50;
     camera.position.z = 100;
}; 

// another test button function
// this does work but then the camera bounces back to what it was looking at before
  </script>



  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: add a JSFiddle please

Comment: you are using orbitControls, the camera moves around a point on a sphere, sphere is a 3D object...

Comment: Even if it is a sphere, camera should just rotate.Why is it moving.I am new to Three.js can you please help me in fixing this.